# What should I pass to throw?

Tags: c++, exception

I added a bunch of exceptions to my hash table class to deal with various issues that might come up. They are mostly constructed like this:

```
std::string msg = std::string("I made doodoo, some value: ") + std::tostring(value);
throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
```

Some of the exceptions are part of normal operation, for example there is one that says the table is full and the thing that catches it then rebuilds the table into a bigger one. I discovered that this puts a sizable dent in the performance though, I suspect its all the string construction. At the same time though, I want the exceptions to be meaningful and make sense to somebody who doesn't know what the code numbers I come up with mean. Whats a good way to deal with this?

Comment: Throwing exceptions in general is expensive. The stack needs to be unwound.

Comment: Exceptions are usually implemented that they provide no overhead until they are thrown, but cause bigger performance drop then.  In this case I would suggest refactoring code to not throw an exception as part of program logic. Save it for cases that are truly exceptional.

Comment: At least make your own exception classes from the pre-define standard exception category classes (like [`std::logic_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) etc.) Don't throw `std::exception` directly, and neither inherit from it directly either unless there's no category that matches your error.

Comment: `Some of the exceptions are part of normal operation` Why? Exceptions are to be used for *exceptional* cases, not for things that are part of normal operation.

Comment: And if your table is full and needs to be enlarged, wouldn't it be better to handle it internally? Without letting the caller handle it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Arguably, part of "normal operation" while programming is writing handling for exceptional cases. :) Yeah, I don't think a storage rebuild trigger is a valid case though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The caller in this case is a "dynamic hash table" which does little more then dynamically resize the internal one. I used to do it internally in the main hash table class but it got really messy and the overhead with 2 classes is less than 5% (in performance) so i prefer this way.

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp - `The caller in this case is a "dynamic hash table" which does little more then dynamically resize the internal one` Adding items to a full table doesn't sound "exceptional" to me.  If for some reason the table is *never* supposed to be full, but for some (weird) reason it is full, then maybe an exception being thrown would be warranted.  Why not return an error code that denotes that the table is full, and you just check for that code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thats what I ended up doing. The reason I went with exceptions in the first place was that I was under the impression that they impose little to no overhead and because they are descriptive by nature which seemed like a nice way to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be creating custom exception classes from `std::exception`. That way when you create your `catch` blocks, you can have a specific `catch` for each of your exceptions. Example:

```
class MyException;            // Inherits from std::exception.
class MyOtherException;       // Inherits from std::exception.

void foo()
{
    if (bar)
        throw MyException();

    if (baz)
        throw MyOtherException();

   // do stuff.
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch(const MyException &ex)
    {
        // Handle MyException.
    }
    catch (const MyOtherException &ex)
    {
        // Handle MyOtherException.
    }
}
```

Creating your own exception classes affords you a lot more flexibility because it allows you to attach additional information to your exceptions, as well as handling different exception types as described above.

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string    m_description;
    int            m_userId;

public:
    MyException(const std::string &errorDescription = "Unhandled exception", const int userId) :
        m_description(errorDescription),
        m_userId(userId)
    {
    }

    int get_user_id() const
    {
        return m_userId;
    }

    virtual const char *what() const
    {
        return m_description.c_str();
    }
}
```

The main problem with your code (at least how you described it) however is that you seem to be controlling your program flow with exceptions. Exceptions are not designed to be fast constructs, they're designed for exceptional cases that would, if not handled, cause your program to crash. Attempting to use exceptions in place of if statements is going to make your code very slow, very hard to read, and even harder to understand/maintain.

To take from your example: if you're adding to a hash table, and need to resize the table, why do you need to throw an exception, when you could just *resize it*? This is exactly how an `std::vector` works. If you do a `push_back()` on a `vector` and `vector.capacity() < vector.size() + 1`, the vector will internally re-allocate the buffer so that the new item can be added. The only time an exception might be thrown is if you run out of memory. The caller isn't aware of any of this, it just calls `vector.push_back(...)`.

Comment: My table is limited linear with a tiny overflow (from my testing this version was the one that gave the best performance). It usually fails to add a value at around ~70-80% full but I don't know exactly when without trying it. Since the data is physically on a memory mapped file, resizing it is a grand ordeal which is why i decided to make my main table class constant size and destroy/rebuild it in a wrapper class that makes it much cleaner. For now I've changed all the exceptions in normal operations to bool return values and I think they'll stay that way.